# Can't get templates from store config?

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, system-config

I tried :

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(); 
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/themes/templates', $store);
```

but it returned null. Where is my fault?
p.s. Value set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the config of the **currently** viewed store:

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

If you want to get the config of one of the **other** stores and not the current one:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $store);
```

I guess you want to get your **current theme**, so you need this:

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/template');
```

Comment: again U help me. TY so much

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 1.9 :**

**Get Store Id :**
`Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();`
**Get Config Value :**
`$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $storeId);`
**as per store vise :**
`$storeId = 2; // ID of the store you want to fetch the value of
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $storeId);`

Comment: Yes, and my sectionName = design, groupName = themes and fieldName is templates

Comment: It's working for you?

Comment: Can U try it for yourself ?

Comment: No, I Just asking you only

Answer (score 0):

**Get Config Value in phtml:**

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('design/themes/templates') ?>
```